# grape: inject parameter dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

If I have this params defined:

```
  params do
    requires :employees, type: Array do
      requires :name, type: String
      requires :surname, type: String
      requires :company_data do 
      # ...
      end
  end
```

And `company_data` is defined in model like this:

```
def company_data=(args)
...
end
```

Basically it something like `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but with some custom logic.

`:company_id` is defined in namespace, and I want to auto assign this param in `company_data` with other values, so that I don't have to iterate through array after params are captured.

```
#company_id: {current_company_id}
```

Comment: isn't `employees` a `Hash`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to have under `params[:company_data]` the result of sending the `params[:company_data]` to the `company_data` method in your model. For that you can use the `coerce_with:` option for grape:

```
params do
  requires :employees, type: Array do
    requires :name, type: String
    requires :surname, type: String
    requires :company_data, coerce_with: ->(data) { object.company_data(data) } do 
    # ...
  end
end
```

Doing this will assign to company_data the result `object.company_data(data)` and after will attempt to validate, therefore if inside the do block you expect the `company_id` you can now add it to the validation inside the block:

```
params do
  requires :employees, type: Array do
    requires :name, type: String
    requires :surname, type: String
    requires :company_data, coerce_with: ->(data) { object.company_data(data) } do 
      requires :company_id, type: Integer
    # ...
  end
end
```